# Processing a single group of rows at once in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration

Tags: java, mapreduce, talend

I have a data source where each row has five fields:

```
company name; year; code; value;
```

In my target output row model I want to produce a row like so

```
company name;year;value1;value2;value3;value4
```

Where value1,value..N are not concatenation for a single code but rather a "mapping". I.e. code 50 => "Total Revenues"

So I need to perform the following logic:

1. First select all the records for the same company name / year
2. Then apply some custom java logic that performs the mapping between my codes and my fields of the output row.

This is a in-memory map reduce with about 1M rows. How should this be handled in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like that, and it's essentially the approach Maira Bay already suggested:

1. Set up your data source to emit those lines one at a time. I used `tFixedFlowInput` for that. You'd probably have to read from a file.
2. Optionally sort by company name and year with a `tSortRow`.
3. Map with a `tMap` the value of each line to the corresponding column in the result line with a guard clause like `input.code.equals("code for this column") ? input.value : null`.
4. Aggregate the rows with a `tAggregateRow`, grouping by company name and year, selecting the first value for each of the value rows - but make sure to ignore the nulls.
5. Do anything you want with the resulting lines.

I tried that with some sample data, hence the `tFixedFlowInput` in step 1, and it worked for me on my machine in TOS 6.3.1.

Beware: the solution proposed assumes you only got one value per combination of company name, year and code.

Comment: how do I ignore the nulls?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 in the component's Basic settings of tAggregateRow there is a table called Operations. In it's fourth column, which should be labeled `Ignore nulls` check the box. (Sorry if labels are slightly different, I have a German localized TOS here.)

Comment: the problem is that for some rows there are some fields which are actually null !

Comment: that's not a problem. the column would just stay empty in the resulting line.

Answer (score 2):

> select all the records for the same company name / year

You might want to use `tAggregate` (https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/18.1+tAggregateRow) to group the flow by company name and year

> apply some custom java logic that performs the mapping between my codes and my fields of the output row.

Talend has a component called `tMap` that allows you to map input fields into output fields.

In your `tMap` you can use something like:

(assuming that `input` is the name of the flow into your `tMap` and `output` is the name of your flow out of your `tMap`)

In `output.field1` put `input.code == 50? input.value : 0`

In `output.field2` put `input.code == 60? input.value : 0`

In `output.field2` put `input.code == 70? input.value : 0`

etc

This is assuming you are ok with leaving the `field` columns with `0` if the `value` was for another `code`.

If you want the `value` for each `code` to be in a different output row out of the `tMap` you can use a logic similar to the above, only putting each test (`code == 70? input.value : 0`) in a different output table, and then filtering out the rows that have `0` (using a `tFilter`) after the `tMap`.

To add output tables you can use the `+` symbol on the top right of the `tMap`.

See here for more detials on how to use `tMap`: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tMap

I hope this helps!

Comment: so a tAggregate groups the flow before a tMap? Brilliant

Comment: Actually it should only work if you put the tAggregate after tMap - like Kriegel suggested . Otherwise you will only get one code and one value for a company/year grouping.

Comment: Good point. Please notice that I said "you might want to use". I didn't say "the right solution is". It was more of a tip for the OP to experiment with the component and see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

See solution below which I believe will fulfill your precise requirement of taking a delimited file data source and transforming it into a denormalized out as specified above.

First I mocked up a file with the same format as you specified.  I made the values a logical concatenation of Company, Year, and sequence.  This makes it easy to verify the output.

[image]

Next I use that as an input, run it thru a sorter, then denormalize on the value field.  Finally you can see the output in a `tLogRow`.

[image]

I also included the component view of `tDenormalize` so you can see how that is done.  You can use this technique in any falvor of `Talend Open Studio`.
[image]

Comment: This handles all the million rows together, also how do I go from a single Value column to multiple columns (I have about 100 columns)

Comment: I can't 100% say if this scales for 1M rows, but part of that will be based on your hardware.  With the technique I described you should be able to set it up quickly and run a volume test.  What was the second issue?  I think your comment got cut off.

Comment: Couldn't edit anymore the comment :( So my problem is not that I need to denormalize in that sense, I need to map to a different field i.e. row1.field1 = (value for the year with code 50), row2.field_2 = (value for the year with code 151) etc etc. The denormalizer doesn't help me with that

Comment: This is introducing new requirements into your bounty question.  Not saying I don't want to help, but when you set a bounty, to be fair to me or anyone spending the time to answer it, it has to be based on the wording of your original question. With that said, I don't understand the idea what your trying to get across in your comment. Sounds like your original question needs a bit of clarification.

Comment: If you look carefully to my question, you see there is no code in my output row model:  there's no denormalization occurring and I explictely mention "custom mapping" in Java. Apologies if my question wasn't clear I will improve it

Comment: I can remove 'code' field from the output mapping, that's a simple task, and can re-post the screenshots if that helps. Please let me know if I should do that, I don't want to waste time if that's not useful.  Re custom mapping, to obtain the output you are asking for does not need custom mapping or code.   Talend has the components for it.  Your output model is denormalized based on Talend's definition- no point in you and me quibbling about their definition.  But either way, their tDenormalize  produces the output you asked for without custom code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139783/discussion-between-edmondo1984-and-e-laroche).